# How to fix some javascript errors in an nginx server

Tags: javascript, laravel, nginx, bower

I'm deploying my code to a prod server which has identical nginx configuration. It's a laravel app. The errors shown in the chrome console log are:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.1
50166f85805d00f05515399fd4c731cc-1557203123:1195 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
uploader.js:319 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).render is not a function
    at uploader.js:319
    at uploader.js:323
(anonymous) @ uploader.js:319
(anonymous) @ uploader.js:323

X.init @ default:730
X.load @ default:728
(anonymous) @ default:743
(anonymous) @ default:744
(anonymous) @ default:746
```

However, the same code is running well on the dev server.
As a result, many javascript functions including pop-ups are not working.

What's the possible cause of this problem?

Comment: Are you minimising the js files?

Comment: I could be that you are missing a file on the server. `$(...).render` is missing. Are you sure that jquery is available?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg it's more likely a plugin that's missing, ie whatever provides the `render()` method

Comment: @RahulRaut yes, the combined js is minimised in the prod but not in dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can fix things up.

The problem is caused by minified js generated by octobercms when `app.debug=false` and `cms.enableAssetMinify=null`. This works fine in dev as `app.debug=true`

So I changed `enableAssetMinify=false` in `app/cms.php`